# Not able to run the app in iPhone Device

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I had a problem with running my app in the device. My device software version 4.2.1 and my xcode is on 4.2. I am using just MessageUIFramework in my app. And my console message is follows. Please help me.

```
 unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file:     unable to 

load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-3893-99
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
run
Running…
[Switching to thread 11523]
[Switching to thread 11523]
continue
unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/info/dns.so (file not found).
warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need to go to the developers website and get your certificate once again. this time match your uuid with your phone and the website.

Answer (score 4):

The framework versions on disk do not match the versions on the device. Delete the folder:

> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/**4.2.1**/

The SDK version (bolded above) can be any installed version. Choose the version(s) of your test device(s).

Plug in your device and start Xcode. Open the Organizer (Window > Organizer) and you will be prompted to restore these frameworks. Once this is complete, restart Xcode and Clean All Targets before building the app for the device.

See: [UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215252/uuid-mismatch-detected-with-the-loaded-library)

Comment: This one also worked for me. Thank god I didn't have to deal with regenerating all the certificates.