# XCode4 Debugging Problem - UUID mismatch detected with libXcodeDebuggerSupport

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uuid, mismatch

after this warning my xcode4 hangs and don't let me continue debugging.

warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3 (8F190)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib

googling on the web I tried unsuccessfully many workaround:

1. remove /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3 (8F190), unplug/plug iphone and reload symbols (this approach unfortunately do not restore libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib)
2. Completely uninstall the development tools
3. Restore Symbols from DeviceSupport/4.3 (8F190)/DeveloperDiskImage.dmg
4. M$ approach (aka reboot computer and/or xcode)
5. clean/rebuild project

None of those and basically all suggestion read into "[UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215252/uuid-mismatch-detected-with-the-loaded-library)" worked for me.

Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this on my iphone 3G (4.2.1, JB) using xCode 4.0.2. Also the solutions on the net didn't help to much since my phone was JB.

It gave me errors about Mismatched UUIDs and stopped after a few of too many were reached. Following the path of what file they were looking for I simply renamed them as they popped up until i brute forced renamed all the files:

```
warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
/Developer4.0.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1
(8C148)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
```

So i renamed the file from:

```
AudioToolbox
```

to

```
AudioToolbox__
```

Then the error was:

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for
/Developer4.0.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1
(8C148)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
(file not found).
```

I'm not sure what this will ultimately do, but it allows me to debug on my JB iPhone 3G (4.2.1) on xCode 4.0.2