# "Unable to read symbols for..." causing to crash iPhone app on device (not with simulator)

Tags: iphone, xcode, build, crash

I hope anybody can help me with the following:

**The problem**

I'm getting the following error when running my app on a device (iPhone 3G):

> > warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/info/dns.so (file not found).

It doesn't display images such as Default.png or other placeholders I'm using. I think that's related to the problem.

**What I've tried**

- Clearing builds, logs etc.
- Removing the folder DeviceSupport and restoring it with my iPhone. This solutions has been approved by 44 people but it did not work for me. See [UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215252/uuid-mismatch-detected-with-the-loaded-library) for more information.

**I'm using (in case it matters)**

- an iPhone 3G with iOS 4.2.1. (8C148)
- Xcode 3.2.5 with iOS 4.2 as latest iOS)
- Also here's the complet log when starting my app. It doesn't crash right away. Only when I go to a specific view.

> > GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1510) (Fri Oct 22 04:12:10 UTC 2010)
> >
> > Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> >
> > GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
> >
> > welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
> >
> > Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
> >
> > There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
> >
> > This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys000
> >     Loading program into debugger…
> >
> > Program loaded.
> >
> > target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-7740-50
> >
> > Switching to remote-macosx protocol
> >
> > mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
> >
> > mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
> >
> > mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
> >
> > run
> >
> > Running…
> >
> > [Switching to thread 11523]
> >
> > [Switching to thread 11523]
> >
> > sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
> >
> > continue
> >
> > warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/info/dns.so (file not found).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how or why but this error disappeared when I corrected 2 other errors.

- First of all I used a placeholder **.png** in **jpeg** format (saved it the wrong way, dumb I know).
- The other thing wasn't too bright either: I mislinked my NIB to a class that didn't exist.

Simulator can handle both, a real device couldn't. But since I fixed these errors, the error in my question disappeared too..

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you have iOS 4.2 with Xcode 3.2.5, but you have 4.2.1 on the device. Do you have the 4.2.1 SDK installed? You need to have the same build (8C148) on both.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have a folder named '4.2.1 (8C148) in my 'DeviceSupport' folder. I also recreated this folder by deleting it and let Xcode restore the folder when connecting my iPhone.. But no luck :(

I found out that the folder 'Latest' was an alias to 4.2. I changed this alias to 4.2.1. but this didn't help either..