# What is the AssistanceServices framework in iOS 5 and how do I resolve this warning?

Tags: ios, xcode4, ios5

What is the AssistanceServices framework and how do I resolve this warning?

warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A334)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssistantServices.framework/AssistantServices (file not found).
warning: No copy of AssistantServices.framework/AssistantServices found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215252/uuid-mismatch-detected-with-the-loaded-library

Comment: I don't think its a duplicate of that one.. this error message is different (although there is a similar reason for it)

Answer (score 1):

you can ignore this warning.. i assume you use an iPhone 4S for debugging? apple didn't publish full device support libraries for 4S (so it needs to read it fromd device) but as this is a private framework it doesn't really matter

Comment: Yes, this is from an iPhone 4S.  Thanks.