# warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, uuid

i have been getting this since updated to 5.0.1

> warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
>     /Users/alfredjunco/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0.1
>   (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation

i also got this one but i don't know if it matters

> unable to load symbol file: warning: Unable to read symbols for
>   /Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib (file not found).
>   warning: No copy of MobileSubstrate.dylib found locally, reading from
>   memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.

Answer (score 5):

Have you recently installed Spire?

If you did, just uninstall Spire and everything will be Ok.

Comment: Would literally never have ever thought of that in a million years.

Answer (score 0):

this generally happens when you do not have device support in xcode ..
You can refer to bellow link for detail answer ..
[UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215252/uuid-mismatch-detected-with-the-loaded-library)

Also listen what jennifer comment above ..

Comment: Comments on that post do not work for me on 5.0.1 which also has a different directory /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

I ran into this on my iphone 3G (4.2.1, JB) using xCode 4.0.2. It gave me errors about Mismatched UUIDs and stopped after a few of too many were reached. Following the path of what file they were looking for I simply renamed them as they popped up until i brute forced renamed all the files:

```
warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
/Developer4.0.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1
(8C148)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
```

So i renamed the file from:

```
AudioToolbox
```

to

```
AudioToolbox__
```

Then the error was:

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for
/Developer4.0.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1
(8C148)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
(file not found).
```

I'm not sure what this will ultimately do, but it allows me to debug on my JB iPhone 3G (4.2.1) on xCode 4.0.2 I had to uninstall xCode 4.2 and reinstall 4.0.2. Also I had to re-install iTunes

Answer (score 0):

Try to use LLDB debugger in stead. Works for me with Spire installed.

How? Click on your targets name (projects name) near the run button and edit scheme.