# Warning: UUID mismatch

Tags: iphone, xcode, uuid, mismatch

I suddenly have an issue with running apps on my decive.
I have iphone 4 with 5.0.1 iOS & since today - when i'm trying to run my app (that worked great 'till now) on my device i get those 2 messages:

```
warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
/Users/Maor/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0.1  (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
/Users/Maor/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
```

Why it's happening?! i didn't change anything on my device or project..
Please help will be appriciated.

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215252/uuid-mismatch-detected-with-the-loaded-library - Please search before asking questions!

Comment: Also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863511/warning-uuid-mismatch-detected-with-the-loaded-library

Comment: Sorry but i forgot to mention that i saw all those posts u've mentioned guys.. but i don't know what to do cau's i don't have 5.0.1 folder in my /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport folder...

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching i found that i had leftovers from SiriPort installation & i didn't thought the installations files includes the damn Spire files. It even wasn't installed at the end because i didn't have enough space at the system partition, that why i was sure from the beggining that Siri is not the issue.
i entered iFile & i saw Spire folder & i realized that this is the problem.
I tried to delete this folder & the iPhone got stuck on the Apple logo...
Unfortunately i made restore & everything back as normal, but thanks to iClude everything went fast :). 15 minutes i had all back.
The applications are now running at my device.

Thanks anyway!