# strange bug on xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215252/uuid-mismatch-detected-with-the-loaded-library)

Yesterday I updated my mac to 10.7.3 
but today when I try to run xcode app on my ipad2, I faced this problem

> warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
>     /Users/mo7amedkhairy/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0.1
>   (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation

I googled it and I found problem like this in 
[UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215252/uuid-mismatch-detected-with-the-loaded-library)

but the solution doesn't fix the problem

--ipad2 has ios5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the device symbols cache, using the following steps:

- Quit Xcode
- Delete the folder 'Symbols' at `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/*IOS_BUILD*/`
- Restart Xcode
- ????
- Profit

Basically, what happened from what it sounds like, is that something happened to the iPad, causing it's UUID to change, and now it's throwing a fit because it thinks that the iPad is a new device.

Comment: i can't find this path ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/

Comment: @mohamedkhairy it's probably because 'Library' is a hidden folder, you must enable viewing it by seeing here: http://osxdaily.com/2009/02/25/show-hidden-files-in-os-x/

Comment: oh still not fixed . same error

Comment: @mohamedkhairy really? There should be no way it has access to the previous symbols if you deleted it. Is there a chance you could try restoring the iPad?

Comment: thanks @Richard J. Ross III for your efforts.